# Bootstrap: multiple targets: is collapsing more than expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was searching for a way to collapse/expand multiple tables at once and I found the folowing method on this site:

```
<button type="button" data-parent="#wrap" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".demo">
    simple collapsible
</button>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="demo collapse">
        test1
    </div>
    <div class="demo collapse">
        test1
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, this works fine, but I noticed that it is also collapsing/expanding other tables with an other parent id. What I need is two buttons that each expand/collapse multiple tables.
As the tables are generated dynamically, they all get a class name that has the same start.

```
<button type="button" data-parent="#wrap1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".demo">
    simple collapsible 1
</button>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="demo collapse 1a">
        test1
    </div>
    <div class="demo collapse 1b">
        test1
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" data-parent="#wrap2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".demo">
    simple collapsible 2
</button>
<div id="wrap2">
    <div class="demo collapse 2a">
        test1
    </div>
    <div class="demo collapse 2b">
        test1
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Some background information, I received a webtool, created with a combination of Python, Django and Iommi. Our Intern created this very nice tool and some of the users had some improvement requests.

The template HTML which creates the different lanes(rows) and each lane contains it's own set of tables. Currently, each table and each lane contains an expand/collapse button, the buttons belonging to the tables work fine, but the buttons belonging to the lanes are manipulating all tables instead of only the tables belonging to that lane.

The template HTML:

```
{% load django_bootstrap_icons %}
{% load mathfilters %}
{% load markdownify %}
<div class="align-self-center" id="lanetypegrouper-{{lanetype.grouper}}">
        {% for lane in lanetype.list %}
        {% regroup lane.blocks.all|dictsort:"position" by position as tblock_positiongroups %}
        <div class="card
            {% if lane.type == 'DIE' %}border-primary {% endif %}
            {% if lane.type == 'FIN' %}border-info {% endif %}
            {% if lane.type == 'PRE' %}border-warning {% endif %}
        {% if lanetype.grouper == False%} ml-auto {% endif%}
        m-2
        tlanetype
        lanetype-{{lane.type}}
        "
        id="lane-{{lane.uuid}}"
        {% with lanewidth=tblock_positiongroups|length|mul:12|add:1 %} style="width:{{lanewidth}}rem; min-width:11rem" {% endwith%}>
            <script>
              var btnUp = '{% bs_icon "chevron-up" %}';
              var btnDown = '{% bs_icon "chevron-down" %}';

              function change_btn(objButton)
              {
                var btnval = objButton.innerHTML;
                $(".collapse").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
                  if (btnval===btnDown) objButton.innerHTML = btnUp;
                  else objButton.innerHTML = btnDown;
                });
                $(".collapse").on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
                  if (btnval===btnDown) objButton.innerHTML = btnUp;
                  else objButton.innerHTML = btnDown;
                });
              }

              function change_row_btn(objButton)
                {
                  var btnval = objButton.innerHTML;
                  $(".collapse").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
                    if (btnval===btnDown) objButton.innerHTML = btnUp;
                    else objButton.innerHTML = btnDown;
                  });
                  $(".collapse").on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
                    if (btnval===btnDown) objButton.innerHTML = btnUp;
                    else objButton.innerHTML = btnDown;
                  });
                }
            </script>
            <div class="card-header  p-2">
                {{lane.get_type_display}}: {{lane.name}}
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary p-1 small" role="button" href="{% url 'laneedit' lane.pk %}">{% bs_icon 'pencil-fill' %} Edit Row</a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary p-1 small" 
                        type="button"
                        data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-parent="#row-{{lane.uuid}}"
                        data-target=".collapse"
                        aria-expanded="true"
                        aria-controls="collapseExample"
                        onclick="change_row_btn(this)"
                >{% bs_icon "chevron-down" %}</a>
            </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div id="row-{{lane.uuid}}" class="row {% if lanetype.grouper == False %}float-right{%endif%}">
                    {% for blockgroup in tblock_positiongroups%}
                    <div class="col tlane-position p-1 m-0" id="laneposition-{{blockgroup.grouper}}">
                        {% for tblock in blockgroup.list%}
                        <div class="card
                            {% if lane.type == 'DIE' %}border-primary text-white{% endif %}
                            {% if lane.type == 'FIN' %}border-info text-white {% endif %}
                            {% if lane.type == 'PRE' %}border-warning {% endif %}
                            tblock-card"
                             id="block-{{tblock.uuid}}">
                            <div class="card-header p-1
                                {% if tblock.notForRelease %}
                                    text-white bg-secondary 
                                {% else %}
                                    {% if lane.type == 'DIE' %}bg-primary {% endif %}
                                    {% if lane.type == 'FIN' %}bg-info {% endif %}
                                    {% if lane.type == 'PRE' %}bg-warning {% endif %}
                                {% endif %}
                                ">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col" style="padding-right:0">
                                        <b>{{tblock.type}}</b> {% if tblock.typeCounter > 0 %}{{tblock.typeCounter}}{%endif%}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-auto small">
                                       <button class="btn btn-sm p-1
                                       {% if lane.type == 'PRE' %}btn-outline-dark {%else %} btn-outline-light {% endif %}
                                      small tblock-collapsebtn"
                                              type="button"
                                              data-toggle="collapse"
                                              data-target="#collapsable-{{tblock.uuid}}"
                                              aria-expanded="false"
                                              aria-controls="collapseExample"
                                              onclick="change_btn(this)"
                                      >{% bs_icon "chevron-down" %}</button>
                                      <a class="btn btn-sm p-1
                                      {% if lane.type == 'PRE' %}btn-outline-dark {%else %} btn-outline-light {% endif %}
                                      p-1 small"
                                         role="button"
                                         href="{% url 'blockedit' tblock.pk %}">
                                        {% bs_icon 'pencil-fill' %}
                                      </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                        {% if tblock.notForRelease %}<span class="small">(SafeLaunch)</span> {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body p-0">{% include 'blocktable.html'%}</div>
                            <div class="card-footer  p-1 m-0"><span class="text-muted small tblock_remarks">{{tblock.remarks|markdownify}}</span></div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %} {% comment %} tblocks {% endcomment %}
                    </div>
                    {% endfor%} {% comment %} tblock grouplist {% endcomment %}
                </div>
              </div>
            {% if lane.desc %}<div class="card-footer">{{lane.desc}}</div>{%endif%}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the best solution, but I solved it with the following code.

```
<script>
  var btnUp = '{% bs_icon "chevron-up" %}';
  var btnDown = '{% bs_icon "chevron-down" %}';

  function change_btn(objButton)
  {
    var btnval = objButton.innerHTML;
    $(".collapse").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){ objButton.innerHTML = btnDown });
    $(".collapse").on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){ objButton.innerHTML = btnUp; });
  }

  function change_row_btn(objButton)
  {
    var lane_id = objButton.offsetParent.id;
    var btnval = objButton.innerHTML;
    var lane_element = "";
    var ids = document.querySelectorAll('*[id]:not([id=""])')
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( ids, function( element, i ) {
      if (element.id === lane_id) { lane_element = element; }
    });

    var new_state = "hide"
    var ids = lane_element.querySelectorAll('*[id^="collapsable-"]:not([id=""])');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( ids, function( element, i ) {
      if (btnval===btnDown) {
        new_state = "show"
        objButton.innerHTML = btnUp;
        $(element).data('toggle', 'collapse').collapse('show');
      } else {
        new_state = "hide"
        objButton.innerHTML = btnDown;
        $(element).data('toggle', 'collapse').collapse('hide');
      }
    });

    var ids = lane_element.querySelectorAll('*[id^="btn-"]:not([id=""])');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( ids, function( step_btn_element, i ) {
      if (new_state==="show") { step_btn_element.innerHTML = btnUp; }
      else { step_btn_element.innerHTML = btnDown; }
    });
  }
</script>
```